# Bulk Insert to Oracle with EntityFramework Sequence Problem

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert to oracle database with EntityFrameworkCore.

Register db context to container

```
services
    .AddDbContext<RepoDbContext>(dbcontextoptions => dbcontextoptions
    .UseOracle(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))
```

In entity type configurator, configure hilo with sequence name. GUID is long.

```
 builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("GUID")
   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
   .UseHiLo("SEQ", "SCHEMA");
```

Run this method with chunked data and chunk size is 10000

```
public async Task BulkInsert<T>(List<T> accountingBillConsensus, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : BaseEntity
{
  await _context.AddRangeAsync(accountingBillConsensus);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

On second call, it throws exception about duplicate key. GUID 2 is already exists. AddRange does not continue from 10001.

Comment: Try to call `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` between bulk inserts.

Comment: Hi Svyatoslav, new exception message on first AddAsync method "The instance of entity type 'XXX' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 10}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached."

Comment: Looks like you are trying to insert already tracked entities. What is the source of the `accountingBillConsensus` parameter?

Comment: public long Id { get; set; }
public string Key { get; set; }
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
public decimal Amount2 { get; set; }
public char Indicator { get; set; }